# How do you split a string in Python with multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, split, delimiter

For example, I could want to split `"Hello>>>World!!!!2]]splitting"` into `["Hello", "World","2","splitting"]`. It doesn't need to be ^that^, but I want to split a string with multiple (say 5) delimiters.
Thanks.

EDIT: I also want to keep the delimiter, making it `["Hello", ">>>", "World", "!!!!", "2", "]]", "splitting"]`

Here's what I've tried:

```
>>> string = "Hello>>>World!!!!2]]splitting"
>>> import re
>>> re.split("(\W)>>>|!!!!|]]", string)
['Hello>>>World', None, '2', None, 'splitting']
```

(I'm new at Regex)

Comment: [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)?

Comment: Can you show your code please with any error messages you are receiving? Also, it would help if you can clearly indicate what parts of your code you're having difficulty with.

Comment: @idjaw I'm uploading it, just a sec...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this using `re.split` you can do:

```
re.split(r'(>+|!+|]+)', string)
```

Explaining this briefly:

- You split on one or more occurrences of the different delimiters (`>`, `!`, `]`).
- In order to include the delimiters in the result, you put the pattern in a capturing group by putting parens around it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: So doesn't that mean that `re.split(r'(\+)', string)` would split the spaces and keep the spaces?

Comment: @Henry Yep, try it, `re.split(r'( )', 'the quick brown fox')`

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

a = 'Hello>>>World!!!!2]]splitting'

print(re.findall('\W+|\w+',a))

['Hello', '>>>', 'World', '!!!!', '2', ']]', 'splitting']
```

What you're doing is finding all word characters *or* non word characters.

Comment: What if it was something like splitting spaces and newlines and keeping both too?

Comment: Just change the regex pattern. You got an example for that? newlines would be `\n` and `\ +` for spaces